# IMongoCollection stats

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm updating my code to use MongoDB new async API.

One of my usages is to get the data size of the collection using :

```
return Database.GetCollection("collectionName").GetStats().DataSize
```

Is there any way to get a `CollectionStatsResult` object from `IMongoCollection` like `MongoCollection.GetStats()` did in the legacy API?
The only option I see for now is to get a Json document and parse it :

```
var jsonCommand = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{collstats : \"collectionName\"}");
var jsonDocument = await Database.RunCommandAsync(jsonCommand);
return Convert.ToInt64(jsonDocument["size"]);
```

Comment: where are you found `.GetStats()`? I downloaded MongoDB.Drive via `NuGet` and it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a strongly-type way in the async API. The results of collection stats continue to change shape, removed certain fields, added others, etc... It wasn't prudent to keep this as a strong-type. What you are doing now by running it manually is the correct way to do it.

If you'd like a strong-type result, you can define a simple class containing the portions you'd like and pass it along.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
class SizeResult
{
  [BsonElement("size")]
  public long Size { get; set; }
}

var result = await database.RunCommandAsync<SizeResult>("{collstats: 'collectionName'}");
```

Comment: Thanks! I will use your suggestion.