# Mongodb configuration from MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I'm new to Mongodb, I'm following a tutorial now, but I'm afraid that the tutorial is a little bit old, I'm getting this error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase' to 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`
This is my code inside my controller class:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public MongoDatabase Database;
        public HomeController()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(Settings.Default.RealEstateConnectionString);
            Database = client.GetDatabase(Settings.Default.RealEstateDatabaseName); //This is the line with the error...            
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Database.GetStats();
            return Json(Database.Server.BuildInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);          
        }
}
```

In the tutorial they are using this:

```
 var server = client.GetServer();//Shows a warning: MongoClientExtensions.GetServer(MongoClient) is obsolete: Use the new API instead
```

and then:

```
Database = server.GetDatabase(Settings.Default.RealEstateDatabaseName);
```

but according to the warning the use of

```
var server = client.GetServer();
```

is obsolete so I need to do it on the other way like I showed firstly, I've tried to cast to `MongoDatabase` but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

you have to  declare your Database as an interface

```
  public MongoDatabase Database;
```

to

```
 public IMongoDatabase Database;
```

the

*`var server = client.GetServer`*

is obsolete  because it was used with the `legacy driver` while you are using the new driver

try this

```
 var res =MongoDatabase.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("{ dbStats: 1, scale: 1024 }"));
```

`res` will look like the following

```
{ "db" : "local", "collections" : 1, "objects" : 5, "avgObjSize" : 1200.0, "dataSize" : 5.859375, "storageSize" : 36.0, "numExtents" : 0, "indexes" : 1, "indexSize" : 36.0, "ok" : 1.0 }
```

Comment: I've tried that already my friend but then the Database.GetStats() method doesn't work inside the Index() action... `'IMongoDatabase' does not contain a definition for 'GetStats' and no extension method 'GetStats' accepting a first argument of type 'IMongoDatabase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I think that in order to GetStats() method to work it should be of  `MongoDatabase` type, any suggestion?

Comment: no even if you use the MongoDatabase there is not any  more the Getstats()

Comment: How can I reach this then?

Comment: when I use MongoDatabase it doesn't shows errors for GetStats()

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
public class HomeController
{
    public IMongoDatabase Database;
    public HomeController()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(Settings.Default.RealEstateConnectionString);
        Database = client.GetDatabase(Settings.Default.RealEstateDatabaseName); //This is the line with the error...            
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Database.GetStats();
        return Json(Database.Server.BuildInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Also there is no `Database.GetStats()` on `IMongoDatabase` you could however create your own extension method to encapsulate this:-

```
public static class MongoDatabaseExtentions
{
    public static async Task<BsonDocument> GetStatsAsync(this IMongoDatabase database)
    {
        return await database.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>("{ dbstats: 1 }")
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, as you mention `Database.GetStats()` is not available on IMongoDatabase...

Comment: read the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331344/imongocollection-stats, the api for the driver changed a while back. so you need to issue the command yourself.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a work around for getting stats on database.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the database from the client instead of the server.

```
Database = client.GetServer().GetDatabase(Settings.Default.RealEstateDataBaseName);
```

This works but even if the `GetServer()` is obsolete, it still runs.